# pythonのscipyで描画したdendrogramの日本語の文字化けを解消したい

Tags: python3, scipy

## scipyで描画したdendrogramの日本語の文字化けを解消したい

scipyで描画したdendrogram中の日本語が文字化けしてしまいます。
コードは下記です。dendrogramの描画自体はうまくいっており、軸ラベルの日本語が表示されません。

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, dendrogram

df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data=[(50,40,30,20,10),(48,38,28,18,8),(40,30,20,10,0),(10,20,30,40,50),(20,25,30,35,40)], index=list("abcde"), columns=list("abcde"))
pdist = pdist(df_sample, "euclidean")
hc = linkage(pdist, metric="euclidean", method="ward")
plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
plt.title("Dendrogram")
plt.xlabel("xlabel", fontproperties=fp)
plt.ylabel("ylabel")
dendrogram(hc, labels=list("abcde"))
```

一応、下記にてmatplotlibの日本語化は試しましたが無効でした。

```
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
fp = FontProperties(fname=r'/Library/Fonts/IPAfont00303/ipag.ttf')
```

versionはpython3.6.0を使用しています。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！ 日本語フォントの使用を試されたということですが、フォントとして指定しているファイル（IPAフォント ipag.ttf）がそのディレクトリにあることは確認なさいましたか？

Comment: [「最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)を参考にコードを質問に記載すると、回答が得られやすいです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。コードが完結するよう編集しました。
ipag.ttfが当該ディレクトリに格納されていることは確認しています。

Comment: `dendrogram()` の場合、xlabel ではなく xtick に描画します。なので、`dendrogram()` の実行後に、`for l in plt.gca().get_xticklabels(): l.set_fontproperties(fp)` とする必要があります。

Comment: metropolisさん、ありがとうございます。解消できました

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/63264